# Django Embeded model formset and model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm a newbie in Django. I want to know how to embed multiple model forms and formsets ?

how to set default or remove fields based on user permission and insert them into one form and get data from users and update/create objects in multiple model?

what views method should I use? class-based views or function-based views?

below there is an example of what I want to do. if you need more information please let me know

this is a report view that will show the detail of the report that the user sent to the website and the admin can change/update/delete status and looted game items of the report and save it each report belongs to one user and one game account. and each looted game item belongs to a report, user, and game account.

[sample of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWZ3a.png)

and there is my models:

```
class GameAccounts(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=400)
     provider = models.IntegerField(choices=GAME_PROVIDER, null=True)
     game = models.IntegerField(choices=GAME_NAME, null=True)
     username = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=400)
     password = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=400)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class GameAccountsHistory(models.Model):
     gameaccounts = models.ForeignKey(GameAccounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
     date_stamp = models.DateField(auto_now=True,null=True)
     time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True,blank=True)
     status = models.IntegerField(choices=GAME_STATUS, null=True)


class LootedGameItem(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
     gameaccounts = models.ForeignKey(GameAccounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
     report = models.ForeignKey(UserReports, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
     name = models.IntegerField(choices=GAME_ITEMS, null=True)
     amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=99999 ,decimal_places=1 ,null=True,blank=True,)
     date_stamp = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
     time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name="", null=True, blank=True)


class UserReports(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
     gameaccounts = models.ForeignKey(GameAccountsHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=False)
     date_stamp = models.DateField(auto_now=True,null=True)
     time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True,blank=True)
     status = models.IntegerField(choices=REPORT_STATU, null=True)
     user_comments = models.TextField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
     admin_comments = models.TextField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
     uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
     working_hours = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False,default=0)
     report_price = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False,default=0)
```

and here is my choices of models

```
GAME_STATUS=[
(1, 'Active'),
(2, 'Deactive'),]

GAME_NAME = [
(1, 'WOW Classic'),
(2, 'WOW Retail'),]

GAME_PROVIDER = [
(1, 'Blizzard'),
(2, 'Steam'),]
GAME_ITEMS= [
(1, 'BlackLotus'),
(2, 'PlagueBloom'),
(3, 'Dreamfoil'),
(4, 'Mountain Silversage'),
(5, 'Groomsblod'),
(7, 'ArcaneCrystal'),
(8, 'BlueSapphire'),
(8, 'DenseStone'),]
```

Comment: Can you include `GAME_PROVIDER`

Comment: *and `GAME_NAME` /  `GAME_STATUS`

Comment: @Danoram added to the question
`code  

GAME_PROVIDER = [
    (1, 'Blizzard'),
    (2, 'Steam'),
]
GAME_NAME = [
    (1, 'WOW Classic'),
    (2, 'WOW Retail'),

]
GAME_STATUS=[
    (1, 'Active'),
    (2, 'Deactive'),

]

 `

Comment: You seem to have just removed all that from my edit. not sure if that was intentional?